# Tabela com múltiplos Radio Button - recuperar valores Vue

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue.js-2, nativescript

Tenho a seguinte tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Que basicamente são disciplinas com suas turmas.

Estou utilizando VueJs, onde tenho um objeto com a JSON com uma lista **Disciplinas** que contém uma lista de **Id turmas**.

A tela é montada usando o código:

```html
<tr v-for="(valor,index) in periodos.Disciplinas">
        <td >
                <input type="checkbox"  v-bind:value="valor.Codigo"
                    v-model="DisciplinaSelecionado" v-on:change="atualizaSimulacao">
        </td>
        <td >
            <h5 class="font-weight-bold">{{valor.Nome}}</h5> 
            {{valor.Codigo}}
            <br />
            IdTurmaSelecionado {{IdTurmaSelecionado}}
            <br />
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4" v-for="(turma,index) in valor.Turmas">
                    <input type="radio" 
                            v-bind:name="valor.Codigo"
                            v-bind:value="valor.Codigo + '*' + turma.IDTURMADISC" />
                    <label class="font-weight-bold">Turma: {{turma.IDTURMADISC}}</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Normalmente basta adicionar um v-model usando um variável criada no Vue que recupera-se o valor selecionado no radio button. Porém como são várias linhas separadas não estou conseguindo o resultado esperado, pois quando adiciono um v-model

```html
<input type="radio" v-bind:name="valor.Codigo"  v-bind:value="valor.Codigo + '*' + turma.IDTURMADISC"   v-model="IdTurmaSelecionado/>
```

Preciso de um array com todos os Id´s Turmas selecionados em cada disciplina no escopo do Vuejs (model).

Answer (score 0):

Olá, o vue já implementa uma solução para este problema. Tendo em vista que você deseja adicionar os itens a medida que eles forem selecionados.
Veja este exemplo retirado da documentação do vue.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#example-3',
  data: {
    checkedNames: []
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="example-3">
  <input type="checkbox" id="jack" value="Jack" v-model="checkedNames">
  <label for="jack">Jack</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="john" value="John" v-model="checkedNames">
  <label for="john">John</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="mike" value="Mike" v-model="checkedNames">
  <label for="mike">Mike</label>
  <br>
  <span>Nomes assinalados: {{ checkedNames }}</span>
</div>
```

Neste caso simplesmente eu usei o "v-model" i iniciei um array vazio e a medida que o usuário for selecionando é adcionado neste array.
De uma olhada na [Documentação](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html) e sobre o vmodel.